# PHP: generated zip has chmod 644

Tags: php, chmod, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive to create Zips and then provide them to download. I save them in a folder and I want to delete all every night (my cronjob would do that).

But now I've seen that they are created using CHMOD 644, and if I try to delete them with my script, I always can't delete them because I do not have sufficient rights.

How can I declare that every new Zip which is created uses 777?

Thanks for help! Flo

Comment: Why not just chmod them correctly using PHP? http://us3.php.net/chmod

Comment: Always use 775 instead of 777.

Comment: Why 775 on a file if the root folder, so my basic directory which is accessible through URL, is 775?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to chmod it like so?

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777);
```

Comment: You are genius. Why does this work with an absolute path but not with a relative path?

Comment: @Florian it should also work with relative paths as far as I know. What error do you recieve with a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to delete files from a directory depends on the permissions of the directory, not the individual files inside. If your directory is 0777, you'll be able to delete the files regardless of their permissions. On the other hand, even if your files are 0777, you might not be able to delete them if your directory is unwritable to your cronjob.

Comment: The problem is, the directory has 755, but the file has 644. So I am able to delete the directory, but I can't because it's not empty.

Comment: The only difference between 0755 and 0644 is that 0755 has the +x (execute) bits set. It has nothing to do with deleting anything.

If your directory is 0777, you'll be able to delete the files inside it, regardless of their permissions. If your directory is 0755, you will NOT be able to delete the files inside it, regardless of their permissions.